# JRadioButton disappearing after being selected

Tags: java, swing

Been experimenting with JComponent and am making a short, 3 question quiz for the user. Since I cannot find the exact area where the code is messing up (or me) I will include my code where it appears. When I click on a button on the JFrame (except for button1), instead of just staying selected, it, along with the other buttons, disappears and the sysout is displayed.

```
public class SimpleQuiz implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton buttona;
    private JButton buttonb;
    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private JRadioButton button1;
    private JRadioButton button2;
    private JRadioButton button3;
    private JCheckBox checkBox1;
    private JCheckBox checkBox2;
    private JMenuItem start;
    private JMenuItem exit;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private ButtonGroup group;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SimpleQuiz();
    }

    public SimpleQuiz()
    {
        //Creates the frame, label, button, textfield. and menubar.
                frame = new JFrame("Classwork 10");
                label = new JLabel("Q1: What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?");
                button = new JButton("Show Answer");
                buttona = new JButton("Show Answer");
                buttonb = new JButton("Show Answer");
                menubar = new JMenuBar();
                button1 = new JRadioButton("24 miles an hour");
                button2 = new JRadioButton("17 miles an hour");
                button3 = new JRadioButton("32 miles an hour");
                fileMenu = new JMenu("File"); 
                exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
                start = new JMenuItem("Start Quiz");
                group = new ButtonGroup();
                group.add(button1);
                group.add(button2);
                group.add(button3);


                //Setting dimensions and properties for the JFrame
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setLayout(null);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                //Setting dimensions and properties for the JButton
                button.setSize(175,50);
                button.setLocation(175, 350);
                button.setActionCommand("exe");
                button.addActionListener(this);
                button.setVisible(false);

                buttona.setSize(175,50);
                buttona.setLocation(175, 350);
                buttona.setActionCommand("b");
                buttona.addActionListener(this);
                buttona.setVisible(false);

                buttonb.setSize(175,50);
                buttonb.setLocation(175, 350);
                buttonb.setActionCommand("c");
                buttonb.addActionListener(this);
                buttonb.setVisible(false);

                button1.setSize(175,15);
                button1.setLocation(150, 300);
                button1.setActionCommand("t");
                button1.addActionListener(this);
                button1.setVisible(false);

                button2.setSize(175,15);
                button2.setLocation(150, 275);
                button2.setActionCommand("v");
                button2.addActionListener(this);
                button2.setVisible(false);

                button3.setSize(175,15);
                button3.setLocation(150, 250);
                button3.setActionCommand("i");
                button3.addActionListener(this);
                button3.setVisible(false);


                //Setting location and dimensions of the first question
                label.setSize(500,25);
                label.setLocation(25, 225);
                label.setVisible(false);

                //Setting dimensions and properties of the JMenuBar and subitems.
               fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
               menubar.setSize(500, 25);
               menubar.add(fileMenu);
               fileMenu.add(start);
               fileMenu.add(exit);
               start.setActionCommand("start");
               start.addActionListener(this);
                exit.setActionCommand("exit");
                exit.addActionListener(this);
                menubar.setVisible(true);

               //adding the JComponents to the frame
                frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
                frame.add(button);
                frame.add(buttona);
                frame.add(buttonb);
                frame.add(button1);
                frame.add(button2);
                frame.add(button3);
                frame.add(label);
                frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("start"))
        {
            start.setEnabled(false);
            label.setVisible(true);
            button1.setVisible(true);
            button2.setVisible(true);
            button3.setVisible(true);
            button.setVisible(true);
        }//End for actioncommand == start.
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("exe"))
        {
            if (button1.isSelected())
            {
                System.out.println("You are correct.");
                label.setText("Q2: Both your arms are cut off. Your opponent taunts you. What do you say?");
                button1.setVisible(false);
                button2.setVisible(false);
                button3.setVisible(false);
                group.clearSelection();
            }//end of if button1 isSelected()
        }//end of actioncomand == exe

        if (button2.isSelected())
        {
            System.out.println("You are incorrect. The correct answer is: 24 miles an hour");
            button1.setVisible(false);
            button2.setVisible(false);
            button3.setVisible(false);
            group.clearSelection();
        }//end of button2.isselected

        if (button3.isSelected())
        {
            System.out.println("You are incorrect. The correct answer is: 24 miles an hour");
            button1.setVisible(false);
            button2.setVisible(false);
            button3.setVisible(false);
            group.clearSelection();
        }//end of button3.isselected.
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("b"))
        {

        }
    }


    }
```

To clarify, I am not finished yet, but since I am just starting out on this project and caught this error I thought I would come and ask for some help :)

P.S sorry for my bad english, I'm originally from Italy.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues, but to solve your specific question: When you click the buttons, it triggers an actionPerformed() event. And in your actionPerformed() method, you're setting the buttons as invisible:

```
if (button3.isSelected())
{
    System.out.println("You are incorrect. The correct answer is: 24 miles an hour");
    button1.setVisible(false);//set button 1 to invisible
    button2.setVisible(false);//set button 2 invisible
    button3.setVisible(false);//set button 3 invisible.
    group.clearSelection();
}
```

Comment: From how I see it, I have it set so that it only checks when the Show Answer button has been clicked. The action command "exe" is only for the show answers button, if I'm correct.

Comment: You've got a misplaced close-bracket then. I just reformatted the code in your question, and added comments to show where each block ends. only the button1.isSelected() is inside the check for "exe".